# Carbon emissions data for UK companies (and beyond UK too)

Tags: data-request, government, uk, europe, environment

I am searching for a carbon efficiency reporting for UK government. To my understanding this data should have been reported in the past as per the CRC scheme in [this](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/crc-annual-report-publications-phases-1-and-2/crc-annual-report-publication-2014-to-2015-and-2015-to-2016) or similar pages. However it appears as data has been removed. Anybody knows where to find this data, or any other data source on carbon emission by companies?

Answer (score 1):

The Environment Agency publishes a dataset titled ["Annual CO2 emissions from regulated installations"](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/4707be1b-e41c-426b-8427-15a01a80e066/annual-co2-emissions-from-regulated-installations) on [data.uk.gov](https://data.gov.uk/).  The data is a pooled cross section of regulated facilities and their emissions between 2013 and 2018.  From the dataset summary:

> Annual emissions of carbon dioxide equivalent from installations in
>   England holding a Greenhouse Gas Emissions Permit under the EU
>   Emissions Trading Scheme. Revision in July 2019 to add 2017 and 2018
>   emissions data. Attribution statement: © Environment Agency copyright
>   and/or database right 2016. All rights reserved.

Comment: The data seems to refer to specific installations, not company-wide. It's a start but I was hoping to find data on at least the largest UK companies.

Comment: Will aggregating to the operator level not work in your case?

Comment: Not enough for my purpose - as there's only a few operators there, out of the tens of thousands of large UK companies that are most likely publishing CO2 emissions somewhere. Still, it's a start :)